# Tooltips of tags not consistent

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, tags

Whenever I hover over a tag item I get a tooltip with information to this tag, except for my favourite tags.

When I hover over one of my favourite tags I only get a tooltip 'show question tagged ...'. It would be nice if the tooltips are consistent. Especially to provide a 'single click' way to subscribe to a tag in my favourite list.

I declare it as bug but you also could call it a feature request.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design at the moment; the favorite tag area is so dense that a large onhover popup would make it fairly hard to navigate.